# Dynamically add Div to html page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I want to have a main div and have the ability to dynamically add new divs at the same level as the main div.
Something like this:

```
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="created_div"></div>
```

Any help would be wonderful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#parent_div").append('<div id="created_div"></div>');
```

or if you want the newly created `<div>`-s to appear before the others

```
$("#parent_div").prepend('<div id="created_div"></div>');
```

Comment: Assuming the original `<div>` was a child of `<body>`.

Comment: @JonathanM Correct. That was an assumption

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#main').after('<div id="created_div"></div>');
```

Comment: This works universally, regardless of what level the original `<div>` is on.

Comment: There is another function insertAfter. But after performs better than insertAfter

Answer (score 4):

```
$('<div id="created_div"></div>').insertAfter('#main');
```